# Automatically move files based on year

Tags: python, file

I am having problems with my code (shown below).

The purpose is to move files based on the year from one folder to another folder.

This is my first go at using Meta data in a program.

I think the "exifread" might be messed.

Any help would be a greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime
import exifread
from shutil import move
 
def get_creation_date(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as image_file:
        tags = exifread.process_file(image_file, stop_tag='EXIF DateTimeOriginal')
        if 'EXIF DateTimeOriginal' in tags:
            return datetime.strptime(str(tags['EXIF DateTimeOriginal']), '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')
        else:
            # If creation date is not found, use the file's last modified date
            return datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file_path))
 
def organize_photos(folder_path):
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
 
        if os.path.isfile(file_path) and filename.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif')):
            creation_date = get_creation_date(file_path)
            year_folder = os.path.join(folder_path, str(creation_date.year))
 
            if not os.path.exists(year_folder):
                os.makedirs(year_folder)
 
            destination_path = os.path.join(year_folder, filename)
            move(file_path, destination_path)
            print(f'Moved {filename} to {year_folder}')
 
# Specify the folder containing your photos
folder_to_organize = '/path/to/your/photo/folder'
organize_photos(folder_to_organize)
```

Replace `/path/to/your/photo/folder` with the actual path of your photo folder. This script will organize the photos into subfolders based on their creation year. Note that this script assumes the creation date is available in the photo's metadata. If not, it uses the file's last modified date.

Suggestion how to revamp the code to make it functional.

Comment: Break this down into smaller problems. If you suspect part of the code is broken, write a way of testing that in isolation if you can.

Comment: Don't "think": just test. Get a file with EXIF data where the file's own timestamp has a different year from the EXIF data, and then write a 3 line program that checks the year, prints it, and then does nothing else. Does it report the correct value? If so, you can cross that off: that works. If not: focus on fixing that, first.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks generally good, but there are a few thing I can add to improvement it, like error handling and handling unreadable files, here's what I'm talking about:

```js
import os
from datetime import datetime
import exifread
from shutil import move
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

def get_creation_date(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as image_file:
            tags = exifread.process_file(image_file, stop_tag='EXIF DateTimeOriginal')
            if 'EXIF DateTimeOriginal' in tags:
                return datetime.strptime(str(tags['EXIF DateTimeOriginal']), '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')
            else:
                return datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file_path))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error processing file {file_path}: {e}")
        return None

def organize_photos(folder_path):
    try:
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)

            try:
                if not os.path.isfile(file_path) or not filename.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif')):
                    logging.warning(f"Skipped {filename}: Unsupported file type")
                    continue

                creation_date = get_creation_date(file_path)
                if creation_date:
                    year_folder = os.path.join(folder_path, str(creation_date.year))

                    if not os.path.exists(year_folder):
                        os.makedirs(year_folder)

                    destination_path = os.path.join(year_folder, filename)

                    # Check if the destination file already exists
                    counter = 1
                    while os.path.exists(destination_path):
                        filename_without_extension, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
                        filename = f"{filename_without_extension}_{counter}{extension}"
                        destination_path = os.path.join(year_folder, filename)
                        counter += 1

                    move(file_path, destination_path)
                    logging.info(f'Moved {filename} from {file_path} to {destination_path}')
                else:
                    logging.warning(f"Skipped {filename}: Couldn't determine creation date.")
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(f"Skipped {filename}: Error processing file - {e}")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error organizing photos: {e}")

# Specify the folder containing your photos
folder_to_organize = '/path/to/your/photo/folder'
organize_photos(folder_to_organize)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I never thought about the error checking.  Of course, I am new to programming. I know enough to be dangerous.   That can be additional to my problem.  

After I posted this question, I found I am having problems with my locations. 
Lets say I want to run this in F:\ documents and move it to C:\Pictures.  
where do I put those folders names in the code? It is not working with those. 
Thanks again.

Comment: If u want to run the script to organize photos in the "F:\Documents" folder and move them to the "C:\Pictures" folder, you would replace the placeholders in the script with the actual paths. example of the script:

# Specify the folder containing your photos (source folder)
folder_to_organize = 'F:\\Documents'

# Specify the destination folder where you want to move the organized photos
destination_folder = 'C:\\Pictures'

Modify the "organize_photos" function, like this:
organize_photos(folder_to_organize, destination_folder):
   pass;

Let me know if I should update the code

Comment: Yes please could you update the code.   That is problem I am having.  When I ran it, I got errors that it didn't like. 

Thank you!!!

Comment: Okay what error are you getting, so I can update it once

Comment: Here is the Syntax Errors
"SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Python27>movefiles.py
  File "C:\Python27\movefiles.py", line 41
    creation_date = get_creation_date(F:\Photos_videos\new_folder)"